# Trying to run tests on a trie, but it's coming up nil and I can't see why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build tests on a Trie retroactively. The trie actually works and returns the words stored, but when I try to run a test against the hash, it tells me the Trie is producing a nilclass.

Here's t9_trie.rb (tweaked to reflect falsetru's v helpful fix)

```
class Trie
  def initialize
    @root = Hash.new
  end

  def build(word) 
    node = @root
    t9num = word.tr('a-z', '22233344455566677778889999')
    t9num.each_char do |ch|
      node[ch] ||= Hash.new
      node = node[ch]
    end
    (node[:end] ||= []) << word
  end

  def find(str) 
    node = @root
    str.each_char do |ch|
      return nil unless node = node[ch]
    end
    node[:end] && true
    node[:end].to_a
  end
end

# words = %w[ant bear cat anu amulet quest question whatchamacalit yes zest]
# words = File.open('dictionary_copy.txt') {|f| f.read }.split

word = "ant"
t = Trie.new
t.build("#{word}")
puts t.inspect
puts t.find('268').class
search = [t.find('268')]
ary = search.to_a
puts ary.class
puts ary
```

And here's t9_trie_spec.rb, which now works:

```
require 'test/unit'
here = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require "#{here}/sandbox"

class StringExtensionTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_if_Trie_exists
    word = "ant"
    t = Trie.new
    t.build("#{word}")
    assert_match /Trie/, t.to_s, "no Trie found"
  end

  def test_if_find_works
    word = "ant"
    t = Trie.new
    t.build(word)
    search = t.find('268') #had to remove extra nested arrays
    assert_send([search, :member?, word]) #and tweak this language
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the error with stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the `print` is `nil`

```
irb(main):001:0> a = print '1'
1=> nil
```

You should remove `print` (or replace `print` with `return`) in the last statement of `find` method:

```
class Trie

  ...

  def find(str) 
    node = @root
    str.each_char do |ch|
      return nil unless node = node[ch]
    end
    node[:end] && true
    node[:end].to_a # <-------------- remove print
  end
end
```

---

Changed test case (also replaced `"#{word}"` with `word):

```
require 'test/unit'

class StringExtensionTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  ...
  def test_if_find_works
    word = "ant"
    t = Trie.new
    t.build(word)
    search = t.find('268')
    ary = search.to_a
    assert(ary.member? word)
  end
end
```